# Items in Multiple Categories Show Multiple Times

Tags: sql

I've got items in an "equip" table that are linked to the equipcat table using a junction table. The problem is that I want to get a list of all items where the user supplied search term is found inside one of numerous fields, including the equipcat (aka category description) field. But **I want each item to only be listed once.**

It seems I must have some fundamental misunderstanding about SQL because I've faced this problem before and had trouble figuring it out. I'm not only looking to solve this particular issue but to also understand it better for future needs.

Here's my SQL. Please ignore the fuzzy searches as I realize they don't scale/perform well. I'm also aware that my use of a single field to hold keywords violates good design and I'm simply asking that you ignore that unless you feel that it is important to the question I'm asking.

```
SELECT equip.equipid, equip.equipdesc, equip.equipgeneraldesc, 
    equip.keywords, equip.dayprice, equip.weekprice, 
    equip.monthprice, equip.hideyn, equipcat.equipcat, 
    equipcat.equipcatkeywords 
FROM (equip INNER JOIN equip_equipcat ON equip.equipid = equip_equipcat.equipid)
INNER JOIN equipcat ON equip_equipcat.equipcatid = equipcat.equipcatid
WHERE (equip.equipdesc LIKE '%rake%' OR equip.keywords LIKE '%rake%' OR 
    equipcat.equipcat LIKE '%rake%' OR equipcat.equipcatkeywords LIKE '%rake%') 
    AND (equip.hideyn = 0)
ORDER BY equipdesc ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  equip.*
FROM    equip e
WHERE   equipid IN
        (
        SELECT  equipid
        FROM    equip_equipcat ec
        JOIN    equipcat c
        ON      c.equipcatid = ee.equipcatid
        WHERE   equipcat LIKE '%rake%' 
                OR
                equipcatkeywords LIKE '%rake%'
        )
        AND
        (
        equipdesc LIKE '%rake%'
        OR
        keywords LIKE '%rake%'
        )
        AND hideyn  = 0
ORDER BY
        equipdesc
```

Comment: To make your suggestion work I had to change equip.* to just * and ee.equipcatid to ec.equipcatid. Also, the first AND you have should be an OR, I believe. I'm trying to return records that might only include 'rake' in the category.

Comment: Actually, upon further testing I think I need to leave your original AND condition in place because I do get erroneous results when I change it to OR.

Answer (score 0):

A) You included fields From table equipcat into your result and thus a line is needed for each category anyways => remove those columns from your query

B) You may then add a distinct keyword to your query (i.e. SELECT DISTINCT...) and reduce multiple lines to distinct ones only.

Comment: Howard, I'm not sure I understand A. What table are you referring to when you say "equiptab"?

Comment: @HK1 Sorry that was a typo. Edited my answer. I meant equipcat.equipcat, equipcat.equipcat.

Comment: Howard, your answer happens to be correct for what I need this query for but it does assume that I'm not making use of the equipcat table's fields in my presentation.

Comment: @HK1 Can you then explain how output should look like for an equip when multiple categories match? In this case one line does not suffice. Or should only one of them be displayed? Which one?